# How to update (edit) a Microsoft Teams message (thread or reply) inside a Teams channel via REST API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I can write a thread message inside a channel in **Microsoft Teams**.
Is there any method to update the content of it via REST API?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply No, Neither **Update** method nor **Delete** method

Two things which is available in Graph API, one is **Post** method and second is **Get** method. This is for messages inside a channel in **Microsoft Teams**.

> Get channel message,

```
GET /teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages/{id}
```

- Documentation: [Get channel message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get-message?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)
- GitHub: [channel-get-message.md](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/api/channel-get-message.md)

> Create chatMessage in a channel

```
POST /teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages
```

- Documentation: [Create chatMessage in a channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)
- GitHub: [channel-post-messages.md](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/api/channel-post-messages.md)

If you want to update channel or calendar event then the API available for them.

- [Patch channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-patch?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) `PATCH /teams/{id}/channels/{id}`
- [Update event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

Some of these APIs are in Beta version, therefore,

> *APIs under the `/beta` version in Microsoft Graph are subject to change.
>   Use of these APIs in production applications is not supported.*
>
> *Idea posted on Microsoft User Voice*, [Update Teams Message/Channel Posts with Graph API.](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/39949165-update-teams-message-channel-posts-with-graph-api)

Comment: Please support this idea to implement it ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

The User Voice idea in Utkarsh's answer is gone.

I have created a new item in the feedback portal, as I couldn't find an existing item.

https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/1b2f43ee-a56f-ed11-a81b-000d3ae32cd0